# SQL Oracle Update containing left join

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, left-join

I want to perform an update for the results of a select query.

```
SELECT
    a.reason,
    n.note
FROM applications a
LEFT JOIN notes n on n.app_id = a.app_id
    AND n.note LIKE '%old%'
WHERE a.code = 'run' AND a.reason IS NULL
```

I thought I could perform these updates separately wrapping the select in an update however I get the error ORA-01733: virtual column not allowed here. How can I go about performing these updates?

```
UPDATE (
    SELECT
        a.reason AS Reason
    FROM applications a
    LEFT JOIN notes n on n.app_id = a.app_id
        AND n.note LIKE '%old%'
    WHERE a.code = 'run' AND a.reason IS NULL
) SET Reason = null

UPDATE (
    SELECT
        n.note AS Note
    FROM applications a
    LEFT JOIN notes n on n.app_id = a.app_id
        AND n.note LIKE '%old%'
    WHERE a.code = 'run' AND a.reason IS NULL
) SET Note = null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update the two tables at the same time. You need two different update statements as follows:

Updating the `APPLICATIONS` table is quite easy as all the records of the `APPLICATIONS` table having `a.code = 'run' AND a.reason IS NULL` will be there in your `SELECT` query.

```
UPDATE APPLICATIONS A
   SET
    REASON = NULL
 WHERE A.CODE = 'run'
   AND A.REASON IS NULL;
```

To update the `NOTES` table, you can use the `EXISTS` clause as follows:

```
UPDATE NOTES N
   SET
    NOTE = NULL
 WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
      FROM APPLICATIONS A
     WHERE N.APP_ID = A.APP_ID
       AND A.CODE = 'run'
       AND A.REASON IS NULL
)
AND N.NOTE LIKE '%old%'
```

You must update the `NOTES` table first and then `APPLICATIONS` table as while updating the `NOTES` table you are using the condition `A. REASON IS NULL` but while updating the `APPLICATIONS` table, you are updating the `REASON` column.